# Dissagregate a field in a aggregated View

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a View which uses agreggation. But when I try to list the taxonomy terms, because of the aggregation, I have only one term listed for each row, instead of all taxonomy terms (multiple terms) listed separated by commas. How can I dissagretate a field, so it displays all the values?

Comment: What is the base table of the View? In other words, what are you viewing? Nodes? And then you are joining in taxonomy terms?

Comment: Yes. I am listing nodes and the node has taxonomy terms associated. Now as the terms are multivalued (several terms) I face the problem.